# Magento - use an alternate "price.phtml" (in addition to the existing one)

Tags: magento

I am looking for a way to have an alternate `template/catalog/product/price.phml` used in one specific location, and to continue using the existing price.phtml file in all other locations.

To explain further, I need to display the regular price, and then another special price right below it - but only on the product page (for the main product being displayed).  This special price is not a price that can be calculated by the catalog price rules, so I wrote my own module to do the calculation. So, everywhere that I am displaying prices I want to display with the regular ol' `template/catalog/product/price.phtml` file... but for the product page (the main product - not the related, upsells, etc) I want to use my own custom `template/catalog/product/price-custom.phtml` template file.  Can anybody help?

Normally I just look in the layout xml files (for example catalog.xml) to find these types of things, but price.phtml is kinda special - it isn't that simple.  And for the life of me I can't figure out if there is an easy way to swap it out conditionally on the page being viewed.  I am aware that I can just update price.phtml to always print out this extra price, and then use css to hide the price everywhere, but I would rather not do that if possible.

(Also you may want to know that I only have simple products.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in your php block.

See example here :

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract

```
protected $_priceBlockDefaultTemplate = 'catalog/product/price.phtml';
protected $_tierPriceDefaultTemplate  = 'catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml';
```

Comment: I took your suggestion and combined it a little with clockworkgeek's suggestion.  Here is an overview of what I did: I I created a class extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract and overrode the $_priceBlockDefaultTemplate variable with the path to my own template file.  Then in the local.xml layout file I did a <reference name="product.info">
            <remove name="product.info.simple" />
            <block type="pmcore/simple" name="product.info.simple.two.prices" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml"/>
        </reference> for <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>

Comment: according to discussion over here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18494/
magento abstact class method cant be overriden using config rewrite can any one confirm it?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in a layout XML file:

```
<layout>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
        <reference name="product.clone_prices">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/price-custom.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
</layout>
```

Comment: Your suggestion was helpful in that it put me on the correct path.  I ended up doing this <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <remove name="product.info.simple" />
            <block type="mymodule/simple" name="product.info.simple.two.prices" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>, where mymodule/simple was a class I created that extended Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: removed "<reference name="product.clone_prices">" with  <reference name="product.info.simple"> and it works like charm! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Create a `local.xml` file, put it in `app/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/layout`

In the `local.xml` file, add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <!-- Override price template on product view page -->               
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
        <reference name="product.info.simple">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/price_product_page.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <!-- /Override price template on product view page -->              
</layout>
```

Create a copy of `catalog/product/price.phtml` and put it in `YOURTEMPLATE/templates/product/product_price_page.phtml`

This will override the **price.phtml** in the template, and replace it with `product_price_page.phtml`

Comment: @Samuel Liew and Ryan Lucier Can you please suggest similar process universally for all product types? I want to use the alternate price.phtml file for all product types.

Comment: @harishannam create a new question, and link to this one.

Comment: @harishannam use the "link" button above the editor window...? Sorry about your suspension; imho, the SE network is too swift to punish or "pile on" peoples' questions... :P

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement recently, where a different price template for the product page was the preferred solution.

The price block appears to be something of a special case in Magento (in the RWD theme at least), it's defined in **catalog.xml** as simply a block type and name within the `<default/>` handle:

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```

If you look around at how some core layout files set the price template, you'll find examples like this (from bundle.xml):

```
<reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
    <action method="addPriceBlockType">
        <type>bundle</type>
        <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
        <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

They call a method called  `addPriceBlockType` which you can find in **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract**

Based on this and after a little experimentation, I found the following solution worked for me:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>simple</type>
            <block>catalog/product_price</block>
            <template>catalog/product/price_product_page.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>configurable</type>
            <block>catalog/product_price</block>
            <template>catalog/product/price_product_page.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <!-- Set for each product type as necessary e.g. bundled, virtual etc... -->
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to achieve it :

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="product.info.simple">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price-product-page.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>

<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.info.configurable">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price-product-page.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

...